# Detect contours only on a part of frame

Tags: java, android, opencv

Is it possible to detect contours on a part of incoming frames?

```
    Imgproc.findContours(threshold_output, contourList, mHierarchy,
            Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Rect rect = new Rect(new Point(0,0), new Point(x,y));
    Mat subMat = incomingFrame.submat(rect);
    // MAKE ONLY CONTOUR OUTSIDE RECT DETECTABLE
    subMat.copyTo(incomingFrame.submat(rect));
```

Comment: An ROI of a `Mat` is also a `Mat`. You can take out the ROI described by `rect` and do whatever you do with a `Mat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to find contours in an image or how to prepare a `Mat` to find contours. You just have to to specify a ROI (region of interest) in your `Mat`.

```
Mat frame = Highgui.imread("image/test.jpg");
// this is not a copy of frame, drawings on frameROI will also appear on frame
// rect describes ROI, starting at x,y = 50 and width, height = 100 
Mat frameROI = new Mat(frame, new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));

// find contours in (processed to improve contour finding) frameROI
Imgproc.findContours(frameROIprepared, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// go through all the contours in my contour list and draw them
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    Imgproc.drawContours(frameROI, contours, i, new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```

After applying this I get this:

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

As you can see it didn't recognise the whole rectangle just parts of it that are inside the ROI.